# Are the two connected components of orthogonal flag bundles isomorphic?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups

Let $X$ be a scheme and $V\to X$ be a vector bundle over $X$. Fix a line bundle $L$ on $X$. We equip $V$ with a symmetric non-degenerate bilinear form $\omega: V \times V \to L$ and say that a subbundle $W \subset V$ is isotropic if $\omega$ restricts to zero on $W$. Let $\dim V = 2n$ and
$$OG_X(n,V)= \{W \subset V \ \vert \ W \textrm{ is an isotropic subbundle of rank } n \}.$$
If $X=spec(k)$ for a field $k$ of characteristic $\neq 2$ it is known that $OG_k(nV)$ splits into two connected components, both being isomorphic to $OG_k(n-1,2n-1)$.

$\textbf{my question}$: Does this hold in general? I could not find such a statement for flag bundles. Pragacz discusses this bundle in his "FORMULAS FOR LAGRANGIAN AND ORTHOGONAL DEGENERACY LOCI" and mentions two families, but not wether they are isomorphic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Stein factorization for the map $OG_X(n,V) \to X$ takes the form
$$
OG_X(n,V) \to \tilde{X} \to X,
$$
where the second arrow is an 'etale double covering, which in general is not trivial. So, in general there is only one component (even over a field, if the field is not algebraically closed and the determinant of the quadratic form is not a square).

Comment: Thank you for this approach. I was kind of expecting this after reading through an example. So what happens if we in fact to have a section, i.e. an isotropic subbundle $W \subset V$ of rank $n$. Does $\mahrm{OG}_X(n,V)$ split as
$$\mathrm{OG}_X(n,V) = \mathrm{OG}^+ \cup \mathrm{OG}^- = \{W \subset V \ \vert \ \dim (W\cap V)_x \equiv n \mod 2 \} \cup \{W \subset V \ \vert \ \dim (W\cap V)_x \equiv n+1 \mod 2 \}$$
?

Comment: If $OG_X(n,V)$ has a section then $\tilde{X}$ has a section, hence splits, and hence $OG_X(n,V)$ splits as well. This splitting is compatible with the splittings over (algebraically closed) fields, hence is given by your formulas.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: It's been a long time, but I have one more (maybe stupid) question: If ${OG}_X(n,V)$ does not admit a section, it it empty then? Since elements in $OG_X(n,V)$ are defined to be maximal isotropic subbundles, i.e. sections.